# Wooden floor material rendering green

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Can anyone give me a tip how to achieve homogenous color of the wooden floor? What am i doing wrong? Parts of the wooden floor are brown, then other parts (behind the bed on the right side)are green... It's like too much of the wall is reflecting of the wooden floor which is nonsense!!

[image] 
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: the floor was generated using floorgenerator, material according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61gNzVKcuLQ

Comment: link to file https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao0n1d17sw3ove7/Scena_spalna2.rar?dl=0

Comment: It looks to me that the green is a reflection of the color of the wall, quite normal if the floors have some gloss.

Comment: Maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36589/how-to-get-rid-of-unnatural-green-glare-from-grass

Comment: Just had a look at a link you provided, that might be the issue, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You will always get more reflections at grazing angles. That is how relity works.    More reading: http://www.3drender.com/glossary/fresneleffect.htm